# How do I use website subdomain for development

Tags: subdomain

I need to develop code and publish to domain.com and the beta version to beta.domain.com

How can i fix that the links on beta.domain.com will be somewhat wrong. They will link to domain.com and not beta.domain.com

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick overview of what we'll be covering.

1. create subdomain on host.
2. install WordPress on subdomain.
3. clone/backup live site using a plugin.
4. import cloned site into development site using a plugin.
5. process updates and test.
6. export development site.
7. import development site into live site (push live)

Comment: I need these to versions to run parallell